# Custom token balance appears 0 (zero) after contract creation

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, erc20

i created a ERC-20 Smart contract token and it is successfully deployed to blockchain.
When i check my wallet(deployed address wallet), amount of that token appears as 0 (zero). 
It looks normal on etherscan.io but in wallet it is not.

it is screenshots of my wallet and etherscan:

[image: Myetherwallet]

[image: etherscan.io]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tokens deployed to MainNet with the symbol "TBT". What you're looking at in MEW is the list of default tokens that have been registered with MEW and the TBT token specifically is referring to a different token contract.

If you look at the list of default tokens's registered with MEW (https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/blob/master/tokens/tokens-eth.json), you will see this:

```
{
    "symbol": "TBT",
    "address": "0xAFe60511341a37488de25Bef351952562E31fCc1",
    "decimals": 8,
    "name": "TBitBot",
    "ens_address": "",
    "website": "https://tbitbot.com",
    "logo": { "src": "", "width": "", "height": "", "ipfs_hash": "" },
    "support": { "email": "info@tbitbot.com", "url": "" },
    "social": {
        "blog": "",
        "chat": "",
        "facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/tbit.bot.5",
        "forum": "",
        "github": "https://github.com/tbitbot",
        "gitter": "",
        "instagram": "",
        "linkedin": "",
        "reddit": "https://www.reddit.com/user/tbitbot",
        "slack": "https://tbotworkspace.slack.com",
        "telegram": "",
        "twitter": "https://twitter.com/tbit_bot",
        "youtube": ""
    }
},
```

Notice that it's a different contract address, so when you try to load your token balance you're actually viewing your balance of this TBT token.

Unless your token is registered with MEW, you can't use the default token list. You have to use the "Add Custom Token" button. Unfortunately, in your case it looks like MEW's UI to show a custom token checks the token symbol instead of the contract address and will error out if it's the same as a default token. So, it looks like you can't view it in MEW.

Comment: Thank you very much. How i can manage that tokens? is there any other way?

Comment: You don’t have to use MEW. There are other tools available. Personally, I would be interested to see if MEW has a ticket to address this issue or some workaround I’m not aware of. They may claim that you shouldn’t reuse token symbols, though.

Answer (score 0):

After messaging with MEW support, they proposed such that way:
i put "2" at the end of symbol and filled rest of information(contract address, decimal) as per token detail and it works.

```
Symbol: TBT2
```